# maui android app build in pipeline failing with error 'The Android SDK directory could not be found'

Tags: android, azure-pipelines, maui, azure-pipelines-build-task, maui-android

Without any code changes the pipeline build for android failing with following errors.

```
/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Linux/33.0.95/tools/Xamarin.Android.Tooling.targets(70,5): error XA5300: The Android SDK directory could not be found. Install the Android SDK by following the instructions at: https://aka.ms/dotnet-android-install-sdk [/home/vsts/work/1/s/App/App.csproj::TargetFramework=net7.0-android]

/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Linux/33.0.95/tools/Xamarin.Android.Tooling.targets(70,5): error XA5300: To use a custom SDK path for a command line build, set the 'AndroidSdkDirectory' MSBuild property to the custom path. [/home/vsts/work/1/s/App/App.csproj::TargetFramework=net7.0-android]

##[error]Error: The process '/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/dotnet' failed with exit code 1
```

```
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'Install MAUI workload'
      inputs:
        command: 'custom'
        custom: 'workload'
        arguments: 'install maui-android'
  
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'Build Solution'
      inputs:
        command: 'publish'
        publishWebProjects: false
        projects: '**/*.sln'
        arguments: '-f:net7.0-android -c:Release /p:BuildAndroidOnly=true'
```

Comment: `dotnet build -t:InstallAndroidDependencies -f:net7.0-android -c:Release /p:BuildAndroidOnly=true ` dint help either

Comment: I set the ANDROID_SDK_ROOT path like in the post from @Tomy and it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

As presented in this github post: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/8952#issuecomment-1886985216

This installs the SDK manually - this should be a temporary solution until Microsoft fixes the builder image.

```
- name: Set Up Android tools
  run: |
    ${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager \
    --sdk_root=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT \
    "platform-tools"

- name: Build
  run: |
    dotnet build <project> \
    -f:net8.0-android
```