# Azure DevOps Pipeline Android SDK not found

Tags: android, .net, azure-devops, maui

It's stop and say: *Android SDK not found.*

My app is in Maui and dotnet 8.

Here is the plan:

```
      - task: NuGetCommand@2
        displayName: 'NuGet restore'
        inputs:
          restoreSolution: '--/--.sln'
          noCache: true
      - task: CmdLine@2
        displayName: workload install maui
        inputs:
          script: |
            dotnet workload install maui-android --source https://aka.ms/dotnet8/nuget/index.json --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        displayName: dotnet build
        inputs:
          projects: ---/---.csproj
          arguments: -c Release -f net8.0-android
```

it says: `Error XA5300: The Android SDK directory could not be found. Install the Android SDK`

Working pipeline that generate the `aab`

Comment: What build agent do you use?

Comment: I'm using a Windows agent. Is this what you wanna know ?

Comment: Yes, but since it windows, I don't have idea what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> Error XA5300: The Android SDK directory could not be found. Install the Android SDK

As per the error, you can manually install the SDK. You can check the android installed, and installed required.

Checked with windows-latest（2022）agent:

```
      - script: |
          C:\Android\android-sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\sdkmanager "platforms;android-34"
        displayName: install

    - script: |
        C:\Android\android-sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\sdkmanager --list_installed
      displayName: check the installed 

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        projects: '**/*.csproj'

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: dotnet build
      inputs:
        projects: '**/MauiSample.csproj'
        arguments: '-c Release -f net8.0-android'
```

please refer to the [similar ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77796319/maui-android-app-build-in-pipeline-failing-with-error-the-android-sdk-directory) for your reference.

If you are using self-hosted agent, you can follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37505738/14996050) to get the command line tool on your agent, and use the sdkmanager to install.

Comment: I try to make it work in my pipeline but I cannot make it work with your solution :-/
There is never a "run" command. Only tasks.

Comment: The snippet is from GitHub Actions. You don't have run in Azure Devops. You should use script in that place.

Comment: @Mafyou, sorry for confusion, i have update the reply.

Comment: @Mafyou, may i know if there's any update? If it's self-hosted agent, please make sure the andriod SDK is installed. Let me know if you have any queries.